# Array elements randomized and written in a new array

Tags: javascript

I got a problem, where I have to create a loop and make it go through an array, shuffling all the elements around and writing the new order with the same elements in a new array, so I can then output the new array further. Anyone know a solution?

```js
 //The array
 var ARRAY = [
        {
            "name1"
        },
        {
            "name2"
        },
        {
            "name3"
        },
        {
            "name4"
        },
        {
            "name5"
        }
    ];
    i = 0;
       while(i < receivedArray.length){
           i++;
           const correctAnswers = StartElements.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * StartElements.length),1)[0];
           answers.answer = correctAnswers.nameLV;
           answers.correct = true;
           answerArray.push(answers);
       }
       //what I've tried, but it doesn't select all the elements in the array, it outputs less than half of them
```

Comment: If you're going to use a snippet then make sure that it "works" (= shows the described behavior/error)

Comment: [How to do a runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).